# How do I create integration/unit test sequencing in vs2012?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, testing

I have some 200 unit tests for an app that run against a simulated piece of hardware with an asynchronous messaging api. All the tests run and pass individually but many of them will fail when run as a group, because of the asynchronous nature of the external calls.

Is there a way that I can set up test sequencing in vs 2012 so that I can add a small delay after each test to give the externals a chance to clear their cache?

**edit:**
The order also seems to matter somewhat, certain tests lock up the external resources longer than others.

I understand that these are integration tests and unit tests together. Much of this is unit testing, much of it is mocked services, and much of it is api integration testing.

I inherited this suite of tests, so the separation of "integration tests" and "unit tests" is beyond my control.

**A little context:** We're interfacing with LabView dlls here, which come with their own set of eccentricities that we're trying to mitigate and instigate.

Comment: Do you use the `MSTest` or something else?

Comment: Just a little note here: If the tests fail because of ordering, they are not _unit_ tests. It's a pretty bad code smell and the cause itself should be fixed, not worked around with a delay/order. If you want end-to-end/integration tests however, there's probably frameworks suited for that.

Comment: Also, per your edit, it looks like your tests are calling external resources directly. IMO the first step you should look into is mocking everything else but the class you are testing. It's not a unit test if it is not in isolation.

Comment: that is yes on MSTest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add a wait with something like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Buy I would instead recommend that you create a simple LabVIEW function that queries the status of all instruments inside of a while loop and "waits" for each one to respond. For example, if you're using GPIB that standard query is:

```
*IDN?
```

You could also look into NI's TestStand product which is specifically designed to coordinate complex asynchronous tests and I believe it has an API you can access from C#.
http://www.ni.com/teststand/whatis/

Comment: The LabVIEW answer is a wonderful idea. I don't know how feasible it is, based on the scale of the application, but there is a point or two that this might prove very helpful.

Comment: Can you please mark it as answered or tell me why the answer is incomplete? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2012 or later there is also fakes which is MS mocks.

Otherwise RhinoMock works fairly good.  Bit of a learning curve.

I have also broken up classes to separate unit test that conflicted with each other.